# Instagrams oEmbed endpoint and a simple URL append endpoind API is returning max width of 658px

Tags: css, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get a max width of 822px for the Instragram images but end up with getting the max-width of 658px. I am using oEmbed endpoint and a simple URL append endpoint. The code snippet is below. I checked the Instagram Developer Documentation, they said that "MAXWIDTH" value is optional and must be greater than 320. https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#oembed

```
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: "https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=" + publicUrl,
          data: {omitscript:true, maxwidth:822, hidecaption:data.info.imageCaption},
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          cache: false,
          success : function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error : function () {
              console.log("error in ajax");
          }
      });
```

Any idea, why is this happening ?